# Most efficient way to gsub strings in awk where strings come from a separate file

Tags: awk

I have a tab-sebarated file called `cities` that looks like this:

```
Washington Washington N 3322 +Geo+Cap+US
Munich  München  N 3842  +Geo+DE
Paris Paris N 4948  +Geo+Cap+FR
```

I have a text file called `countries.txt` which looks like this:

```
US
DE
IT
```

I'm reading this file into a Bash variable and sending it to an awk program like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

countrylist=$(<countries.txt)
awk -v countrylist="$countrylist" -f countries.awk cities
```

And I have an awk file which should split the `countrylist` variable into an array, then process the cities file in such a way that we replace "+"VALUE with "" in $5 only if VALUE is in the countries array.

```
{
  FS = "\t"; OFS = "\t";
  split(countrylist, countries, /\n/)

  # now gsub efficiently every country in $5
  # but only if it's in the array
  # i.e. replace "+US" with "" but not 
  # "+FR"
}
```

I am stuck in this last bit because I don't know how to check if `$5` has a value from the array `countries` and to remove it only then.

Many thanks in advance!

[Edit]

The output should be tab-delimited:

```
Washington  Washington  N   3322    +Geo+Cap
Munich  München N   3842    +Geo
Paris   Paris   N   4948    +Geo+Cap+FR
```

Comment: Could you please post expected output in code tags and let us know then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, if I understood your requirement correctly.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]=$0;next} {for(i in a){if(index($5,a[i])){gsub(a[i],"",$5)}}} 1'  countries.txt  cities
```

A non-one liner form of code is as follows(you could set `FS` and `OFS` to `\t` in case your Input_file is TAB delimited):

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$0]=$0
  next
}
{
  for(i in a){
    if(index($5,a[i])){
      gsub(a[i],"",$5)
    }
  }
}
1
'  countries.txt  cities
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Washington Washington N 3322 +Geo+Cap+
Munich München N 3842 +Geo+
Paris Paris N 4948  +Geo+Cap+FR
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. the oneliner works —  gsub(a[i],"",$5) should be gsub("+"a[i],"",$5) in order to get rid of the plus sign, but that's a minor point. The problem is that I don't know where to stick 'FS = "\t"; OFS = "\t";' since both my input file and my output file need to be tab-delimited. I need to run this from Bash, and when I put 'FS = "\t"; OFS = "\t";' in the BEGIN section of the awk file, the result is not correct

Comment: @Tench, Yes we should put `FS` and `OFS` in `BEGIN` section, if `\t` is not working then it could you don't have exact tabs in your files?

Comment: you're right —  my test file didn't have real tabs, but when I tried it on my actual file, it worked. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is the awk way of doing it:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"                # delimiters
}
NR==FNR {                      # process countries file
    countries[$0]              # hash the countries to an array
    next                       # skip to next citi while there are cities left
}
{
    n=split($5,city,"+")       # split the 5th colby +
    if(city[n] in countries)   # search the last part in countries
        sub(city[n] "$","",$5) # if found, replace in the 5th
}1' countries cities           # output and mind the order of files
```

Output (with actual tabs in data):

```
Washington      Washington      N       3322    +Geo+Cap+
Munich  München N       3842    +Geo+
Paris   Paris   N       4948    +Geo+Cap+FR
```